# How to edit particular row in a table by popping a form modal in vuejs?

Tags: html-table, modal-dialog, vuejs2

I am using a modal form to add new details to the row of a table. After adding details, I’m just adding edit and delete buttons at the end of it. Now here delete button is working fine. How to edit a row of a table by popping replicate of form modal by clicking “edit” button in a row.
Here’s my code:

```
<div class="layout-padding">
        <div
          class="item item-link"
          v-for="modal in types"
          @click="$refs[modal.ref].open()"
        >
          <i class="item-primary">add</i>
          <div class="item-content has-secondary">
            <div>{{modal.label}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <q-modal ref="maximizedModal" class="minimized" :content-css="{padding: '50px'}">
    <div class="main">
      <label>Enter Your Name:</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name" v-model="YourName">
    <br>

    <label>I am:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="Male" value="male" v-model="picked">
    Male
    <input type="radio" id="Female" value="female" v-model="picked">
    Female
    <br>    

    <div class="button">
      <button class="red" @click="$refs.maximizedModal.close()">Close</button>
      <button class="blue" v-on:click="sub" @click="$refs.maximizedModal.close()">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </q-modal>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th> </thead>
    <tbody class="result">
        <tr v-for="(h, index) in final">
            <td v-for="(value, key, index) in h">
                    {{ value }}
            </td>
            <td><button id="edit" class="green edit" v-for="modal in types"
          @click="ed(h, index);$refs[modal.ref].open()" type="submit">EDIT</button></td>
            <td><button id="delete" class="red delete" v-on:click="del(index)" type="submit">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And my script is:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {YourName: '',
      details: [],
      final: [],
      types: [
        {
          label: 'Add Details',
          ref: 'maximizedModal'
        }
      ],
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sub: function () {
      this.details = {
        'name': this.YourName,
        'gender': this.picked,
      }
      this.ed()
      if (index === '[object MouseEvent]') {
        this.final.push(this.details)
      }
      if (index > -1) {
        this.final.splice(index, 1, this.details)
      }
      else {
        alert('else')
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.details))
        this.final.push(this.details)
      }
    },
    del: function (index) {
      this.$delete(this.final, index)
    },
    ed: function (details, index) {
      return index
    }
  }
}
```

If edit button is clicked, the same row should be edited. I don’t know how to proceed further. Please, guide me.

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: since I'm using Quasar, I'm not able to provide exact replicate in js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'splice' can able to modify the given array of object.

Can simply include this inside an 'if' loop:

```
this.final.splice(this.indi, 1, this.details)
```